# Truncated Display of Amounts in UltraGrid for data Type double

Tags: infragistics

I am using infragistics.UltraGrid and I am having a problem with the truncated display of amounts in the grid..The column is in double as datatype..is there anybody know how to fix it?Changing the width and setting it as multiline has no use....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your UltraGridColumn for a currency datatype.
This could be done in the designer if you define the columns of your datasource, otherwise you could do something in code (perhaps in InitializeLayout event)

```
 int integerNumbers = 10;  // The max count of integers in the currency value
 int decimalNumbers = 2;   // The max count of decimals in the currency value

 // If you write this in the InitializeLayout then you could 
 // use e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns
 UltraGridColumn cl = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["yourColumnKey"];

 // Align on the right side 
 cl.CellAppearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Right;
 cl.Header.Appearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Right;

 // Format the maskinput
 cl.MaskInput = string.Format("{{currency:-{0}.{1}}}", integerNumbers, decimalNumbers);
 cl.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.Currency;
```